# biblatex-dw and op. cit

Tags: biblatex, biblatex-dw

Using `biblatex-dw` with `footnote-dw` style, I've noticed the lack of "op. cit." and "loc. cit." trackers. Is it possible to generate "op. cit." and "loc. cit." for repeating citations in footnotes, just like in `verbose-trad1`?

For example, I have the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english,french,polish]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\DeclareQuoteAlias{croatian}{polish}

\usepackage[style=footnote-dw,backend=biber,]{biblatex}

\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\addbibresource{Praca magisterska.bib}

\begin{document}
    This is a document\cite[92]{deleuze_kino._2008}. We can see this is a document\cite[60]{ryan_narrative_2001}. This is another document\cite[93]{deleuze_kino._2008}.

    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

With the following 'Praca magisterska.bib' bibliography:

```
    @book{deleuze_kino._2008,
    location = {Gdańsk},
    title = {Kino. 1. Obraz-ruch, 2. Obraz-czas},
    isbn = {978-83-7453-896-1},
    abstract = {Koncepcja obrazu-ruchu charakterystycznego dla kina atrakcji przeciwstawiona modernistycznemu modelowi obrazu-czasu.},
    publisher = {Słowo/\-Obraz Terytoria},
    author = {Deleuze, Gilles},
    translator = {Margański, Janusz},
    date = {2008}
}


@book{ryan_narrative_2001,
    location = {Baltimore},
    title = {Narrative as Virtual Reality: Immersion and Interactivity in Literature and Electronic Media},
    isbn = {978-0-8018-6487-2},
    shorttitle = {Narrative as Virtual Reality},
    publisher = {Johns Hopkins University Press},
    author = {Ryan, Marie-Laure},
    date = {2001}
}
```

I have such an output in the footnotes:
[image]

So, I would like to know if in the repeating citations it is possible to generate a footnote like "Deleuze, op. cit., s. 93", instead of "(see note)" references.

Comment: Not that your question is unclear, but you could make our lives a tiny bit easier by providing an MWE/MWEB so we have something to start from. That MWE could also show us the exact cases for 'op. cit.' and 'loc. cit.' you have in mind. Would you also want 'ibid.' to enter the mix?

Comment: What should happen to 'op. cit.' and 'loc. cit.' if there are several works by the same author. In that case a blind application of 'op. cit.' as defined by the `\loccit` tracker (as used by `verbose-trad1`) of `biblatex` can lead to two different sources being output as 'Name, op. cit.' depending on the context of the citation.

Comment: @moewe I have clarified the question with the example above. I hope that makes it more clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We need to add `\ifloccit` and `\ifopcit` logic to the `cite` bibmacro of `footnote-dw.cbx`. The two macros `cite:opcit` and `cite:loccit` are straight copies from `verbose-trad1.cbx` with the tiniest modification to work together with `biblatex-dw`.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=
footnote-dw,
opcittracker=context,
loccittracker=context,
backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\makeatletter
\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
  \usebibmacro{cite:citepages}%
  \global\boolfalse{cbx:loccit}%
  \bibhypertarget{cite\the\value{instcount}}{%
    \ifboolexpr{
      test {\ifciteseen}
      and not 
      bool {cbx:textcitefull}
    }
      {\iffieldundef{shorthand}
         {\ifthenelse{\ifciteibid\AND\NOT\iffirstonpage}
            {\usebibmacro{cite:ibid}%
             \usebibmacro{cite:save}%
             \usebibmacro{cite:reset}}
            {\ifthenelse{\ifciteidem\AND\NOT\boolean{cbx:noidem}%
                                    \AND\NOT\iffirstonpage}
              {\usebibmacro{cite:idem}}
              {\ifnameundef{labelname}
                 {}
                 {\usebibmacro{cite:name}}}%
             \ifopcit
               {\ifloccit
                  {\usebibmacro{cite:loccit}}
                  {\usebibmacro{cite:opcit}}}
               {\usebibmacro{cite:title}}%
             \usebibmacro{cite:save}}}
         {\ifboolexpr{togl {cbx:shorthandibid}
                      and test {\ifciteibid}
                      and not test {\iffirstonpage}}
            {\usebibmacro{cite:ibid}}%
            {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}
          \usebibmacro{cite:save}%
          \usebibmacro{cite:reset}}}
      {\ifthenelse{\ifciteidem\AND\NOT\boolean{cbx:noidem}%
                              \AND\NOT\iffirstonpage}
         {\usebibmacro{cite:idem}%
          \booltrue{cbx:idemfull}}
         {}%
       \usebibmacro{cite:full}%
       \usebibmacro{cite:save}}}}

\newbibmacro*{cite:opcit}{%
  \printtext[bibhyperlink]{\bibstring[\mkibid]{opcit}}}

\newbibmacro*{cite:loccit}{%
  \printtext{%
    \bibhyperlink{cite\csuse{cbx:lastcite@\thefield{entrykey}}}{%
      \bibstring[\mkibid]{loccit}}}%
  \global\booltrue{cbx:loccit}}
\makeatother

\DeclareDelimFormat{nametitledelim}{\addcomma\space}


\begin{document}
Lorem\autocite[380]{sigfridsson} ipsum\autocite[40]{knuth:ct:a} dolor\autocite[380]{sigfridsson} sit\autocite[50]{knuth:ct:a} amet\autocite[10]{knuth:ct:b} consectur\autocite[381]{sigfridsson} schlorem\autocite[10]{knuth:ct:b}

consectur\autocite[381]{sigfridsson} g\autocite[50]{knuth:ct:a} dolor\autocite[380]{sigfridsson} sit\autocite[50]{knuth:ct:a}

consectur\autocite[381]{sigfridsson} f\autocite[50]{knuth:ct:a} dolor\autocite[380]{sigfridsson} sit\autocite[51]{knuth:ct:a}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You're definitely a TeX.SX hero. :) I was initially going to comment on the question along the lines: "short of implementing it from scratch, it's not possible". And there it comes!

Comment: @moewe Again, very thanks for the help! Works perfectly :)